Is it possible to reference and transpose each staff separately for midi output only in lilypond?
I wanted to create a setup, where I can generate a full score as well as each part and separate registers using lilypond. For the most part, my setup works fine, however I have some issues transposing the midi output for the different instruments correctly.
Here is the setup:

In my source material I always have the instrument pitch available for each part (meaning the notes the person playing a certain instrument sees)
The full score in my source material also displays the same notes, so not the concert pitch

I think it woud be relatively easy to transpose everything to concert pitch (= c), but I want to output the sheet music as is since I will probably need this setup in the future.
So the question now is, how to transpose each part in a register output or the full score output according to the instrument?
Here is what I tried so far (example with a part of the clarinet register).
\version "2.24.3"
\include "_global_definitions.ly"
\include "clarinet_eb.ly"
\include "clarinet_1.ly"
\include "clarinet_2.ly"

\header {
  instrument = "Clarinets"
}


\book {
  \bookOutputName "register_clarinets"
  \score {
    \midi {
      \context Staff = "pitch_es" {
        \transposition es 
      }
      \context Staff = "pitch_bes"{
         \transposition bes 
      }
     }
    <<
      \new StaffGroup = "StaffGroup_clarinets" <<
        \new Staff="pitch_es" {
          \set Staff.midiInstrument = "clarinet"
          \clarinet_eb
        }
        \new Staff="pitch_bes" {
          \set Staff.midiInstrument = "clarinet"
          \clarinet_two
        }
      >>
    >>
  }
}

This does transpose something (i have tested this with A-B sound tests), but sounds horrible so my guess is something with the context references is wrong. The actual notes in clarinet_eb and clarinet_two should be correct, I have checked those multiple times now.
So my question boils down to: can I transpose the midi output of each staff in the score corresponding to the respective instrument without changing the sheet music displayed in the pdf

\transposition is exactly there to control MIDI transposition. It will not affect visuals, but only exported midi. So it suffices to do
\new Staff \with {
  \transposition bes,
} c''

(of course adapted to your case). Also check out the Documentation here:
https://lilypond.org/doc/v2.25/Documentation/notation/instrument-transpositions

Man, I have spend so much time with this and it is so simple. Thank you so much!

btw: Is there a list somewhere to find all instruments transpositions (with correct octave).

@RolandDeschain https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_transposing_instruments
